# Hide Toolbar while in full screen mode

Tags: mac, menu-bar, fullscreen, ventura

I am talking about the toolbar that appears under the menubar when hovering over it with the mouse (with red closing & green fullscreen button)

As I'm using keyboard shortcuts to go in fullscreen and leave it and also to minimize windows, this toolbar is completely unnecessary and annoying to me.

Does anyone know how to deactivate it? I guess there is no functionality by default, so it's also fine when there is a third party software existing to change this behavior
(or maybe someone can explain how to control this with applescript or swift)

Thank Y'all!
[image: Annoying Toolbar in full screen mode]

Comment: I could not replicate the problem with Safari (as I don't have Edge) so it may be Edge thingy. Looking at screenshot I also have a question - are you 100% sure that this is fullscreen?

Comment: @AivarPaalberg It is fullscreen. OP has the cursor hovering over the bar and its pulled down over the browser's tabs. This maybe an Edge side-effect as you suggest, I've seen similar behaviour in other 3rd party apps eg Discord, where the bar with the buttons overlays something else (odd UI API usage). Also the orientation of the green button is arrows-in, thus already zoomed full, with the option to unzoom. To OP - The toolbar's behaviour is standard, it would not be able to be accessed by mouse only if there were some option to hide it. It's good to have more than one way of doing something.

Comment: Hey, yeah it's fullscreen. I placed this topic at the Edge Developers Forum today, and got many confirmations from users facing the same "problem". I guess it will be fixed soon by microsoft.

Comment: I never found a fix for it, but a solution. 
Use Firefox. Join the Open Source Army. Customize the CSS if you don't like the design and sync on a NAS if you are unhappy with the sync functionality.
Case Closed :D Thank you all!

Comment: Since the toolbar is native macOS you cannot CSS customize it. On firefox the behavior is it pushes the window out of the way instead of ontop. MacOS window API makes it tricky for developers to implement correct toolbar behavior

Comment: @LlamaD'Attore 
Yeah and thats how it should be imo ^^ 
Push that damn menubar out of my way :D  `git push -f menubar `